# How to check if a certain contact in my contact list has Whatsapp?

Tags: android, contacts, whatsapp

I would to know if a certain contact for example named "Michael" in my contact list has Whatsapp or not.
I found an error but eclipse is telling me that it does not recognize the word "activity" in the code and the other thing is that I don't know where to put the name of the contact in the code. So can you please help me with that?

```
    String[] projection = new String[] { RawContacts._ID };
String selection = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND account_type IN (?)";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { "THE_CONTACT_DEVICE_ID", "com.whatsapp" };
Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
boolean hasWhatsApp = cursor.moveToNext());
if (hasWhatsApp){
    String rowContactId = cursor.getString(0)
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible! You can't check on your Device if a contact you have, has Whatsapp or any application for that matter.